# What's the correct way to describe in Russian a beam-ceilinged room?

Tags: терминология

What's the correct way to describe in Russian a beam-ceilinged room, that is, a room with wooden beams in its ceiling?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `здание/комната c перекрытиями балочного типа`.

Here's [a quote](http://samdomstroy.by/roofs/floor-timber.aspx):

> По типу конструкции перекрытия, применяемые в индивидуальном
>   строительстве можно разделить на две группы:
>
> - балочные – состоят из несущего элемента (балки) и заполнителя, обеспечивающего тепло- и звукоизоляцию.
> - безбалочные – выполняемые из готовых плит или панелей.

`Балочный` here is derived from [`балка`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) which [is](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) predictably a beam.

Comment: Can we call them "потолочные балки"?  I mean more colloquially in fiction. I happen to need the thing.

Comment: Yes, I think we can. At least that's what I would call them.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, those are different types of "перекрытие", respectively, "перекрытие без подшивки потолком", and two cases of "[дом, здание] без чердачного перекрытия". I wouldn't know the English terms off the bat, though.